# In pre-push hook, get "git push" command full content?

Tags: git, shell, githooks, git-push

When a Git `pre-push` hooks script is working, how to get the full `git push` command content?

Example, when I run: `git push origin master`, pre-push hooks executed.
I want to get `origin` & `master` in this hook.

How can I get the list of arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR summary: you need a while loop

Your hook script (assuming sh/bash) should include a loop of the form:

```
while read localname localhash remotename remotehash; do
    ... code here using $localname etc ...
done
```

#### Description

All of the Git hooks are described in [the githooks page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).  The `pre-push` hook description begins with:

> This hook is called by *git push* and can be used to prevent a push from taking place. The hook is called with two parameters which provide the name and location of the destination remote, if a named remote is not being used both values will be the same.
>
> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook’s standard input with lines of the form:
>
> ```
> <local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF
> ```
>
> For instance, if the command `git push origin master:foreign` were run the hook would receive a line like the following:
>
> ```
> refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345
> ```
>
> although the full, 40-character SHA-1s would be supplied. ...

The first paragraph means that in a shell script, `$1` and `$2` are the name of the remote—e.g., `origin`—and its URL, or the URL repeated twice if the user ran:

```
git push https://some.host.name/some/path ...
```

The *second* paragraph is **important**.  A `git push` command can push *more than one branch*.  For instance, I can run:

```
git push origin feature-A feature-B
```

to push both `feature-A` *and* `feature-B`.  You *must* read *all* input lines, one line at a time, to discover what is to be pushed.  The *current* branch in the repository is not important: reading `HEAD` will give you the wrong answer *unless* the user happens to be pushing the current branch.  On the other hand, most users mostly just push the current branch.  This will give you the illusion that your hook is 100% reliable, when it's actually only 92.37% reliable.<sup>1</sup>

As the documentation notes, the hook gets the *full name* of each reference.  If you are pushing a branch, that full name starts with `refs/heads/`, but you can push a tag, in which case the full name starts with `refs/tags/`.  To write a reliable hook, you must inspect the full name, rather than simply stripping off the first two components.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Like 38.61% of statistics, this one was made up on the spot. :-)

<sup>2</sup>There are a lot of bad sample hooks (not all of them pre-push hooks) out there that use:

```
branch=$(echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3)
```

If you are pushing tag `v2.3`, this hook will think you are pushing a *branch* named `v2.3`.  If you are pushing a branch named `bugfix/1234`, it will think you are pushing a branch named `bugfix`!  The `cut` technique is just wrong, but a quick fix for the latter is to use `-f3-`, which at least produces `bugfix/1234`.  It's better to verify the first components of the ref—i.e., do something like:

```
case $ref in
refs/heads/*) ... it's a branch ...;;
refs/tags/*) ... it's a tag ...;;
*) ... it's something else entirely, such as refs/notes/* ...;;
esac
```

Once you know the prefix, you can use `${ref#refs/heads/}` or `${ref#refs/tags/}` to strip off the known prefix and get the full but unqualified branch or tag name.  If many cases, though, you can just work directly with the full reference name.

Answer (score -1):

Those params are passed to the hook

In the hook you can get the branch name like this:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
```

If you wish to view those settings in your terminal as well and not as part of your script use those commands:

```
# get the name of the tracking branches
git branch -a -vv

# or: 
git status -b --porcelain

# to get the name of the current branch:
git symbolic-ref -q HEAD
```

---

#### How to by-pass the `pre-push` hook?

```
git push --no-verify
```

Comment: Thanks  codewizard, i  also want  to get  branch information,eg:"master",  but,  $1  and  $2 are  both  not. how  to get  branch information?

Comment: I prefer `git status -b --short` over `git status -b --porcelain`. It provides the same information in a more readable way if you enabled the `color.status` configuration ( default ). The `porcelain` option disables color by default.

Comment: agreed here :-)

Comment: @SebTu: `--porcelain` is meant for scripts, where color would get in the way of the script interpreting the output. `--short` is meant for human consumption, where color is useful unless you're colorblind :-)

Comment: -1; your `sed` incantation returns the wrong result if the branch name contains a `/`. Better to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to directly get the current branch name (without the `refs/heads` prefix) and avoid having to perform such manipulations.