# How to get the list of files that will be pushed in git push?

Tags: git, lint

I need some generic command (without specyfing any branches name), that will give me list of files that will be pushed in git push. There might be few commits on branch that will be pushed. So basically I'd like to get all files from local commits. I guess I'd need to compare to last commit that is on remote, but I don't know how to do it

I need it because I want to add pre-push git hook that will lint files that are being pushed.

I tried
`git diff @{upstream} --name-only`
and it does what I need, but it only works if I have upstream of branch set. Otherwise I'll get error `fatal: no upstream configured for branch <branch-name>`

Is there any way to do it in generic way even for branches without upstream set?

Comment: `git status` ? Or, if you have already commited, use `git log --1` to see details of latest commit.

Comment: What if I have many commits to push? Can I filter those out somehow?

Comment: [`pre-push` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) is fed on stdin list of 4-tuples (local-ref locall-commit remote-ref remote-commit). For every line read run `git diff --name-only $remote-commit $locall-commit` . Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42462882/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+%22pre-push+hook%22

Comment: @phd thanks, but unfortunately, without upstream set, remote commit is only zeroes (as pointed in prepush documentation - https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks 
But thanks for effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question:

```
git log --format="%H" HEAD --not --remotes
```

This will give me hashes of all commmits that are on my local branch, but on on remote.

I just need diff between most recent commit and parent of the first commit:

```
git diff --name-only <first_commit>~ <last_commit>
```

And this will output list of files that will be pushed to the remote

Comment: Beware, according to the documentation it may lead to unpleasant results:

**git log --branches --not --remotes** : Shows all commits that are in **any** of local branches but not in any of remote-tracking branches. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-codegitlog--branches--not--remotesorigincode

Comment: You're right, but I don't use --branches parameter, instead I use HEAD

Comment: What is `<first_commit>`? What is `<last_commit>`? The command to find the commits looks correct, but shouldn't you inspect each commit's changes?

Comment: @j6t well, the first command will give me list of commits. And first_commit and last_commit are first and last commits on the list. Now when I compoare last commit to the parrent of first commit, it will give me summary of what happened in all commits between

Comment: @MG This works only, if you are pushing just one branch and that branch does not have a merge commit. A better way would be to use `--boundary`, and then compare the pushed commit, `HEAD`, against each boundary commit (they are marked with a leading `-`). Also, use `git rev-list` instead of `git log --format="%H"` and `git diff-tree -r --name-only` instead of `git diff --name-only` in your scripts.

Comment: @j6t I'm looking into it. In meantime, after your edit the first command doesn't work. Not sure why, I guess HEAD shoul be right after log ?

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected it. `--not` is a switch that negates all subsequent refs. Therefore, `HEAD` must be before `--not`, because it is a positive ref.

Comment: @j6t you're right, it sometimes doesn't work with merge. If I merged some pushed commits, my git diff included files from those commits (obviously). I tried with --boundary flag, and it works better, but I have no idea why. Also I don't see difference (in this case) between diff and diff-tree, what is it? Also thanks for git rev-list

Comment: `git diff-tree` and `git rev-list` are "plumbing" commands, whose output will not change as Git evolves. Output of `git diff` and `git log` is not guaranteed to be stable.

Answer (score 4):

you simply want to compare your current branch with origin:

```
git diff --name-only mybranch origin/mybranch
```

when you don't have upstream set, somehow you must have the remote branch available locally one way or the other. Otherwise what are you trying to compare ?

You need to understand how git works. Git is a local copy of the remote repository. All operations are done locally and then pushed to remote repository. Compare is the same in that sense, you must have a local copy of the remove branch to be compared with something else.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a generic command for that, which will not use name of my branch. I want to use it in pre-push hook, so it needs to work for any branch

Comment: Or, if you care about the current branch: `git diff --name-only @{u}`

Comment: unfortunately @{u} is the same as @{upstream}, which is close, but it doesn't work if there's no upstream set for the branch as I mentioned in post

Comment: ??? How can git _guess_ against which commit it will diff against? So... multiple commits.... after what commit?

Comment: what do you mean by upstream not set ? where does you branch then come from ?

Comment: @Dmitry you can create branches at any commit.... so it's trivial to create branches without upstream.

Comment: @eftshift0 Git doesn't need to guess, I want to specify it somehow, but I don't know how. Basically I want to compare to the last commit that is on origin

Comment: M G, what do you mean by origin. You just created a branch and there is nothing on remote , what do you want git to do ? how would it know the second point for compare?

Comment: `origin` is a remote.... it's got potentially plenty of commits and branches... and the branch you are talking about has no upstream setup.... so what do you want to go against? you might try `git diff --name-only origin/@` to try to match the remote branch with the same name.

Comment: Actually, just tested git doesn't like that syntax. So you will have to pray and fall back to this: `git diff --name-only origin/$( git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @ )`. It's flaky, let me tell you.

Comment: origin is not a remote origin can represent anything you like. the question remains , what one actually wants.

Comment: @eftshift0 I tried it, unfortunaly I got error:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/branchName': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: @Dmitry In this case I meant remote. I want to get all files from my local commits

Comment: Sure.... that probably means that the branch does not exist on `origin` or you haven't fetched.... I think you are expecting git to guess a lot more than it makes sense.

Comment: @m-g can you tell me what exactly would be the remote ? do you already have the remote ? before you go into hooks world , first make it work as normal git commands, for instance, what happens when you run command in my post ?

Comment: @Dmitry when I call command from your original answer, I get fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/mg/testGit': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

This is because I don't have upstream set for my branch (it doesn't exist on remote yet). 
And answering your first question, what exactly would be remote - I mean commit that was pushed to remote repository at some point. There's remote, and there's my local repo. I have some commits on my local repo that don't yet exist on remote. Push does exactly this - it pushes them to remote. And I want to know what files will be pushed

Comment: if there is no remote yet: How do you think git would know what diff you want to produce ? between which commits ? When you push a new branch it first asks to set upstream, doesn't it ? you can't just push. where would it push ?

Comment: Yes, and by default upstream will be set to origin/myBranch. But regardless of that, I will push local commits to remote. Git knows which commits are only local, and which are on remote

Comment: it only knows it after you set the remote/upstream. Because then it can compare the upstream with your new branch. Before that, it simply does not know.

Comment: No, of course it know before it. Git knows everything about each commit. It obviously knows whether or not a commit is on remote or not. You need to learn more about git before you start helping others

Comment: M G - Please try to read what i am trying to explain you,before suggesting to get educated. When git pushes commits it does not push your original branch or its commits, it pushes modification of the local copy of the remote branch, namely origin/mybranch. That is why it asks you first to set upstream. Once again: Grasp the concept of the "Git is a local copy of the remote repository". If you don't tell what your local branch represents on the remote, git will not tell you what it is going to push. In your case git is not even going to push anything as such there is no diff in the first place.

Comment: Well, of course git needs upstream to push. But that's not the point. As I said many times, my goal is to get all commits that will be pushed, and that are not on remote (regardless of upstream). And I dont need upstream to know which commits are those

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you, I hope it is me who does not know how git works. I wish you all the best, I hope you find the answer.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks, I think I found my answer, this command gives me commits I wanted: git log HEAD --not --remotes

Comment: that command did not return anything for me. I created a new branch, made one commit and executed the command. Nothing came out of it.

Comment: ok, it did produce the commit. but it is still not what you want: because : Shows all commits that are in **any** of local branches but not in any of remote-tracking branches.  - - which means if you have more than one un-pushed branch it will show all local commits from all branches. and my simple test proves it, create two branches and make commits on both of them and then run your command., see what happens.